# Proving that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x_0 + \int\limits_0^\infty e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds=\vec{0}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider $x'=Ax+b(t)$, a system of differential equations. Given that $A$ has negative real parts in all its eigenvalues, and that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} b(t) = \vec{0}$, I need to prove that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x_0 + \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds=\vec{0}$.

Well, it's clear with $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x_0 = \vec{0}$. But I'm struggling with $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds$. Can someone please give me a hint?

I feel like I don't know some property which should be used here, such as a property of integrals.

Comment: I suppose that you also assume that $b(t)$ is uniformly bounded, i.e. you exclude cases like $b(t)=\frac{1}{(t-T)^2}$?

Comment: There is a neat trick related to this question if we take into account @CTNT 's comment. To provide a good estimate for the integral, split it into two parts: from $0$ to $\frac{t}{2}$ and from $\frac{t}{2}$ to $t$. In both integrals we use estimations for $b(t)$: for first integral $\| b(t) \| \leqslant M$, where $M = \sup\limits_{t \geqslant 0} \| b(t) \|$; for second integral $\| b(\tau) \| \leqslant \sup\limits_{\tau \geqslant \frac{t}{2}} \| b(\tau) \|$ and this supremum goes to 0 as $t \rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, that's exactly what I had in my mind!

Comment: @CTNT It's still pity for me that one evening I almost figured that trick by myself, but was too impatient and spoilered the answer :) so, the credit goes to a great book that I still can't remember (I think it was Lefschetz or Hartman; less likely it was Wiggins or Meiss).

Comment: @CTNT: no such condition was given on $b(t)$.

Comment: @Evgeny: it's clear with $b(t)$, but what happens with $e^{-As}$? Because the eigenvalues of $A$ are negative, does this imply that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{-As} \to \infty$?

Comment: @sequence Oh, it's simple: you have to estimate norm of $e^{A(t-s)}$ when $s \leqslant t$. Because of last condition the eigenvalues of $A(t-s)$ have negative real parts too.

Comment: @Evgeny I think that's what I did but I wasn't sure if my argument was rigorous enough.

Comment: @sequence If you did it like $\| \int\limits_{0}^{t} A(\tau)\, d\tau \| \leqslant \int\limits_{0}^{t} \| A(\tau) \|\, d\tau \leqslant \int\limits_{0}^{t} \alpha(\tau)\, d\tau$ and you can evaluate last integral, then it was rigorous :)

Comment: @Evgeny what is $\alpha(\tau)$

Comment: @AzJ It was a placeholder for an estimation of norm $\| A(\tau) \|$